# "translator of" or "Translator for"

Tags: grammar, american-english, formal-language

Is "English translator of this company" correct or "English translator for this company"?

I want to introduce my job somewhere and the position I work in it and I don't know which one is more formal and correct.

Comment: As an actual translator, I would say: at "for" is OK but the meaning is slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, "of" is usually used for situations where there *can be* only one such position in the company, for example the CEO or President of the company. For any other position, you would use "for." So in the first case, you would say

> I am the CEO of Acme Widgets.

but in other cases you would use

> I am an/the English translator for Acme Widgets.

Comment: Would you consider the following incorrect? "I serve as a vice president of ABC Corporation." "I'm the Vice President of Marketing for ABC Corporation."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan hmm, both of those are definitely correct, even though they don't fit the guidelines I came up with. Evidently it is actually more complicated than that

Comment: I think that what you said is generally true but that there are some gray areas.